# Can't open Google Assistant settings

Tags: huawei, google-assistant

I cannot open the Google Assistant settings on my Huawei P10. Whenever I try, it shortly looks like it goes to a new window, but then immediately goes back to the previous window...

I have tried restarting the device. Google Assistant has been enabled on the device for a long time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on multiple Huawei phones. The only thing I have found to work is a factory reset. You can back up your phone first if you have anything you want to save, but I've only gotten it to work with a full reset of all data. When I restore the backup, sometimes it stops working again, sometimes it doesn't. I think it's a problem with the EMUI skin, because I have had no problems with it on custom ROM's on Huawei devices. Hope you get it working!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll give that a shot and let you know. It's a shame though, I really like Huawei phones.

Comment: I love Huawei phones! I have the Mate SE at the moment, and it works great so far. Good luck, and don't forget to back up data you need!

Comment: Resetting the phone did indeed work. I accepted your answer but I can't upvote it because I don't have enough rep. Thanks a lot!